# Eigenfunction and solution of differential equations

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenfunctions

Hello i am trying to find a book or a pdf for the analytical relation between the eigenfucntions and the solution of differential equations , why are we trying to find eigenfunction? And of course how the characteristic polynomial was made. I want analytically proofs.

Comment: You should say that your concern is about the very specific diff. equations that are linear differential equations with constant coefficients. A reference among many others: (http://math.clarku.edu/~ma130/lindiffeq.pdf).

Comment: Sorry i didn't mention for the specific differential equations.

Comment: There is an old book by Titchmarsh on eigenfunction expansions for second order DE's I think. That might be available free as a pdf somewhere or in your college library.

Comment: This book from 200 years ago by Joseph Fourier is the place where serious eigenfunction analysis first arose as a general means of solving partial differential equations. https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Analytical_Theory_of_Heat.html?id=No8IAAAAMAAJ These techniques predate eigenvector analysis for matrices.

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis Do you have a background of linear algebra?